# Java - sumar distancia N en string

Tags: java

Estoy tratando de editar un código para que, dado un string, se hagan los siguientes cambios:

- si es mayúscula, pasa a minúscula y viceversa
- a la letra le corresponde otra que está a N posiciones de distancia.

El código que tengo hasta ahora es:

```
private static final String ALPHABET = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

public String code(String text, int distance) {
    // cambio mayus <-> minus
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(text);

    for (int index = 0; index < sb.length(); index++) {
        char c = sb.charAt(index);

        if (Character.isLowerCase(c)) {
            sb.setCharAt(index, Character.toUpperCase(c));
        } else {
            sb.setCharAt(index, Character.toLowerCase(c));
        }
    }

    // comparación de letra con ALPHABET
    for (int i = 0; i < sb.length(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0, j < ALPHABET.length(); j++) {
            //tiene en cuenta mayusculas y minusculas
            if (sb[i] == ALPHABET[j] && sb[i] == ALPHABET[j].toUpperCase()) {
                // suma la distancia
                sb[i] = ALPHABET[j+distance];
            }
        }
    }

    return sb;
}
```

No estoy seguro de haberlo hecho bien, pero hay partes que no sé cómo hacerlas. Es decir, `ALPHABET` es circular así que si la longitud es mayor de 26, de la 'z', pasará a la 'a' de nuevo. Esto no lo sé expresar.

Cómo lo haríais?

Gracias!

Comment: Para recorrer un array "circularmente" sin salirte, lo mejor es usar el resto de la división, puesto que el resto también es circular (el resto de cualquier división siempre está entre 0 y el divisor). Si divides `distance` entre la longitud de tu cadena, ***SIEMPRE*** te va a dar un valor entre 0 y la longitud de tu cadena (en este caso, ALPHABET). Algo así: `int distanciaSinSalirse = distance % ALPHABET.length()`. Así cuando la distancia sea 27, te dará 1

Comment: @Benito-B entonces esto que sugieres, lo sustituyo por el bucle que tengo actualmente o lo hago por separado al recorrer con ```int i``` e ```int j``` como he hecho? Gracias

Comment: Eso lo pones en donde necesites que sea "circular" sin ser en el bucle. Los bucles ya los estás haciendo de 0 a `ALPHABET.length()`, así que ahí no tiene mucho sentido, no? Pero cuando sumas `[j + distance]` sí que puedes salirte! Ponlo en cualquier parte que necesitas que sea *circular*, y no se salga